# How to extract time series with NCO

Tags: nco

I have a single netcdf file with monthly precipitation data from 1998-2016. The extent of the file is (14.75,-90.5,15.75,-88.75) with a cell size of 0.25 by 0.25. So 8 columns and 5 rows. How can I make time series graphs using NCO for specific cells or for the whole extent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A timeseries for each point can be extracted with, e.g.,

```
ncks -d lat,15.0 -d lon,-90.3 in.nc out.nc
```

The whole extent can be averaged with

```
ncwa in.nc out.nc
```

The [manual](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncks) ably answers these questions.